# Spring AOP custom annotation alternatives

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am working on a library which would allow clients to capture runtime data in their code. I am following the below steps.

I am planning to do the following:

1. Create a Annotation in Library.
2. Use Spring AOP and create a Aspect and define a Pointcut and Advice with the annotation. Implement the logic to capture the runtime data.
3. Let client add the lib as a dependency and put the annotation to the methods they want the runtime data to be captured.

Is there any alternative way in Spring AOP to achieve this instead of defining Annotation? Basically any other way of interfacing library and client code?

Comment: R.G already answered correctly. Let me just add that I think it is horrible that most AOP users somehow start with the least favourable way to use AOP: by adding marker annotations everywhere. AOP is meant to work without scattering annotations all across your code base, and it does. Using marker annotations IMO is only a last resort, if there is absolutely no other way to express the targets you want to apply your aspect to in a pointcut.  The best aspect is one which does not need that kind of crutch.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP supports the following [AspectJ pointcut designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/ataspectj/pointcuts.html) (PCD) in addition to the one used: `execution`,`within`,`this`,`target`,`args`,`@target`,`@args`,`@within` .

also an additional Spring AOP specific PCD `bean`

The current approach explained is based on `@annotation` PCD.

Do read through the [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.html) for further information.